# why update or save() does not work in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, react-native

I am trying to update table (fetching from my react native app to laravel) and i always get error. This is how i fetch:

```
fetch("http://192.168.2.45/backend/public/api/checkuser", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    })
```

my laravel api:

```
Route::post('update','mainController@update');

 public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $email = $request->email;


        $error_message="DENIED";
        $Success = "Success";


       if (user::where('email', '=',$email)->count() > 0) {
        $user = user::where('email', '=',$email);
        $user->image_name = $request->email;
        $user->save()--->
      here i get my error
      ( i have also tried where(....)->update(....)
      and i get the same error)
          return response()->json(['message' => $Success]);
         }else{
           return response()->json(['message' => $error_message]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Post your error.

Comment: Please specify the error

Comment: the error i get : ''console.error:''error:",{"line":22855",column":16",sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"}............ which is the same error i get every time i have written something wrong in laravel php files...i think that laravel doesnt recognise methods save(),update() for some reason... (btw thanks for responding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `where` the result back is a `Query Builder` and not an item of your user model on which you can call CRUD operations. So you should get the result back and call save on it, so replace your block with this one:

```
if ($user = user::where('email', $email)->first()) {

    $user->image_name = $email;

    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => $Success]);
}
// no need for an else block

return response()->json(['message' => $error_message]);
```

And to explain `first()` will return `null` if a record is not found, which means `false` condition and it will return your error message, if found it will update your `image_name` to the email. (Which does not make sense, but it is your code)

Comment: again i have the same error . if put out the ''$user->save();''  it runs again though but does not update my table (yeah do not worry about image_name :P )...i have also put in my user model  protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image_name',
        'image_path'
    ]; but it didnt help

Comment: Did you used my code as I gave it to you? Can you try `return $user` after the `if` statement to make sure that the correct user is returned back?

Comment: 1) yes i copied exactly your code , and 2) i returned  user's name and its the correct user...but still the issue with save()

Comment: Can you please copy and comment here exactly the error that you get because I don't understand what is going on this way?

Comment: the error i get in my android : the error i get : ''console.error:''error:",{"line":22855",column":16",sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"} ... but i assume that  does not help you a lot :P ( also thanks mate)

Comment: This does not helps at all. I am just curious how do you test that the user is the correct one? Try in `tinker` if you can make the same steps. Get the first user using the email address, change the `image_name` to the email, and call save on it, and see if that returns an error.

Comment: yeah...i think i am starting to understand whats going on...the error i get by running via tinker is (Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users` set `image_name` = G, `users`.`updated_at` = 2019-06-05 00:41:50 where `id` is null)')

Comment: but the thing is that i dont use users table, but i have created ''user'' table instead

Comment: So if you don't have a `id` column in your model, you will need to replace the `primaryKey` on the model to some other field, like the email for example.. so put this in your model: `protected $primaryKey = 'email';`

Comment: and if you changed the table name you will need `protected $table = "user";` to let eloquent know which table you are referring to.

Comment: Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `image_name` = G, `users`.`updated_at` = 2019-06-05 00:49:52 where `email` = G).. now i get this error

Comment: If you don't have timestamp columns for `updated_at` and `created_at` then add `protected $timestamps = false;`. If you go a different route please read the docs my friend.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Access level to App\user::$timestamps must be public ..that means i should include timestamps in order to run it?

Comment: no, just add `public $timestamps = false;` instead. I gave you wrong modifier for the property

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaaah man it worked!!!!!! Thank you soooooooo much mate..i wish i could do something for you too :P thanks mate , i am one step closer to get my master now :P

Comment: I am glad I helped. Have fun and congrats on your masters once you get it :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the query.Your search not returning results.

```
$user = user::where('email', $email)->first();
if(isset($user))
{
$user->image_name = $email;
$user->save();
return response()->json(['message' => $Success]);
}
else
return response()->json(['message' => $error_message]);
```

Comment: my fault is that i did not have these commands ->  (protected $primaryKey = 'email';
    protected $table = "users"; 
    public $timestamps = false;) in my user  model, but still thanks